# ImportError: No module named sklearn.cross_validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using python 2.7 in Ubuntu 14.04. I installed scikit-learn, numpy and matplotlib with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-numpy \
python-numpy-dev python-scipy libatlas-dev g++ python-matplotlib \
ipython
```

But when I import these packages:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

It returns me this error:

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn.cross_validation
```

What I need to do?

Comment: perhaps your module name is wrong if you have installed sklearn and anaconda correctly.

Comment: I am really just repeating it, but you have to use sklearn.model_selection from now on. cross_validation is not usable since sklearn 20+

Comment: Wow 13 answers to say the same thing. The latest 4 years after the first one (in case bits would fade with time I suppose)

Answer (score 814, accepted):

It must relate to the renaming and deprecation of `cross_validation` sub-module to `model_selection`. Try substituting `cross_validation` to `model_selection`

Comment: Why didn't sklearn developers put in an alias for backward compatibility? Also, the doc for that older version should indicate this refactor: https://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html.

Comment: Because making code inoperable with API changes is one of the favorite features of python-based data science ;-) (See Pandas decade of version 0.x changes)

Answer (score 187):

train_test_split is now in model_selection. Just type:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

it should work

Answer (score 45):

I guess cross selection is not active anymore. We should use instead model selection. You can write it to run, `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

Thats it.

Comment: This is the Answer. You are awesome.

Answer (score 36):

Make sure you have [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download) installed and then [create a virtualenv using conda](http://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/). This will ensure all the imports work

```
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Mar  9 2015, 16:20:48) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

Comment: No, I don't have it, I need to install Anaconda?

Comment: Well,I would suggest you to install it.But You can also try sudo apt-get install python-sklearn,that should work.

Comment: The answer by @DimaLituiev is really the correct answer here.  This issue is mostly related to a renaming, not a true missing package.

Comment: This isn't necessarily needed. You are suggesting installing a new environment just for one package that was renamed, I would say this solution is an overkill. Dima's solution should be marked as correct answer

Comment: I guess the question should have addressed if he has "import sklearn" worked or not first. If it works, maybe this is not a naming issue.

Comment: Note that you don't have to have Anaconda to fix this issue (I just use pip). See other answers for a possible fix.

Answer (score 30):

`sklearn.cross_validation` is now changed to `sklearn.model_selection`

Just use

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

I think that will work.

Answer (score 24):

```
sklearn.cross_validation
```

has changed to

```
sklearn.model_selection
```

Checkout the documentation here: 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html

Answer (score 17):

May be it's due to the deprecation of sklearn.cross_validation.
Please replace sklearn.cross_validation with sklearn.model_selection

Ref-
https://github.com/amueller/scipy_2015_sklearn_tutorial/issues/60

Comment: It appears your answer is the [same as a previous given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844352/10400050) in the same thread. If you think that answer can be improved, consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34844352/edit) it instead of making a new answer to the same question.

Comment: @Johan Some how I did not see the other answer. I could delete my answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 13):

Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Comment: Same solution as ayat ullah sony's answer.

Answer (score 10):

Past : `from sklearn.cross_validation`
(This package is deprecated in 0.18 version from 0.20 onwards it is changed to `from sklearn import model_selection`).

Present: `from sklearn import model_selection`

Example 2:

Past : `from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score` (Version 0.18 which is deprecated)

Present : `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score`

Answer (score 10):

`sklearn.cross_validation` is now changed to `sklearn.model_selection`

Just change

```
sklearn.cross_validation
```

to

```
sklearn.model_selection
```

Answer (score 10):

The `cross_validation` is not available anymore.

Try to use `model_selection` instead of `cross_validation`:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have code that needs to run various versions you could do something like this:

```
import sklearn
if sklearn.__version__ > '0.18':
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
else:
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

This isn't ideal though because you're comparing package versions as strings, which usually works but doesn't always. If you're willing to install `packaging`, this is a much better approach:

```
from packaging.version import parse
import sklearn
if parse(sklearn.__version__) > parse('0.18'):
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
else:
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 5):

change the code like this

```
# from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 4):

`train_test_split` is part of the module `sklearn.model_selection`, hence, you may need to import the module from `model_selection`

**Code:**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Answer (score 3):

cross_validation was deprecated some time ago, try switching it out with model_selection

Comment: try adding more explanation to your answer to give it more value.