# No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I'm using anaconda , when I import

```
import sklearn as sk
```

It works 
but when import :

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

It returns:

```
No module named 'sklearn.cross_validation'
```

I checked the environment and scikit-learn is installed  what do I need
   to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named sklearn.cross\_validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667525/importerror-no-module-named-sklearn-cross-validation)

Answer (score 41):

As pointed out by @amit-gupta in the question above, `sklearn.cross_validation` has been deprecated. The function `train_test_split` can now be found here:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Simply replace the import statement from the question to the one above.

Answer (score 7):

What's your sklearn version? You can find out with `sk.__version__`

It's possible that it has been moved to `sklearn.model_selection`

Answer (score 6):

For Sklearn 18 version import this:
"from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold"

For sklearn 20 import this:
"from sklearn.model_selection import KFold"

Answer (score 2):

There should be another import:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

Answer (score 2):

simply replace sklearn.cross_validation with sklearn.model_selection